# how and where to use standard input flush in java?

Tags: java

```
import java.io.IOException;  
import java.util.Scanner;

public class fflush{  

    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException{  

    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);  
    int a;  
    System.out.print("Enter an integer:");  
    a = input.nextInt();  
    String b,c;  
    System.out.print("Enter a string:");  
    b = input.nextLine();  
    System.out.print("Enter another string:");  
    c = input.nextLine();  
}

}
```

//result is//

Enter an integer:4
Enter a string:Enter a nother string:

Comment: If your "question" text doesn't contain any question marks, there's a good chance it's not actually a question. Tell us what you've tried and exactly what problem you're having. Don't expect us to divine your intent from a free-floating block of code. See [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only "flush" the output in Java.

I suspect you mean, when to discard the rest of the line. To do this you can call

```
input.nextLine();
```

You need to do this after nextInt() as you expect to be reading from the next line.