# x86 inline assembly language how to flush keyboard input cache

Tags: visual-c++, x86, inline-assembly

I want to write an input validation, users can input name with whitespace, if it is `null` or exceed the maximum array length, it will `jmp` to the beginning. However, when the input is too long, `\n` would be left over the second turn, which means `scanf_s` would receive the value automatically in the second turn. So I imagine is there a method like Java `fflush` in the inline assembly language to clear keyboard input every turn? This is my code:

```
char inputName[] = "%20[^\n]";
char name[20];
int  validNum;
_asm{
   startInput:
    lea     eax, name 
    push    eax 
    call    scanf_s //this is the problem part 
    add     esp, 8

   computeLength:
    lea     ebx, name
    ...
    inc     validNum 
    cmp     [ebx], '\0'
    je      validate 

    validate:
    cmp     validNum, 20
    jg      startInput
   }
```

Comment: Sorry, this is just my problem, I googled around and could not find what is the specific command and how to use it.

Comment: You push the address of `name` twice, instead of pushing the format string first.  Are you sure your code works at all?

Comment: I'm not sure `fflush` is what you're looking for.  If you want scanf to skip a newline, use a format string of `"\n%20[^\n]"`.  If that's your problem, this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer.  Err, actually that might make scanf eat any whitespace, rather than just an optional newline.

Comment: Actually, I want to **check** the array is `null` or ` exceed`, your method works I needn't flush cache because users could input right in the scanf_s part, but I want to validate the array and then jump to the beginning let user reinput.

Comment: BTW, it's not a "cache", it's a buffer.  And BTW, ISO C `fflush( stdin )` (or any other input stream) is undefined behaviour (http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush).  In POSIX, the behaviour is defined for seekable input files: the underlying file descriptor position is repositioned to match the stdio position.  (I.e. it discards the input buffer, along with any `ungetc` data).

Comment: According to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18493390/how-and-where-to-use-standard-input-flush-in-java, there's no `fflush` in Java, and `flush()` only makes sense on output streams.

Comment: Re: your last update: now you only pass one argument, and still no format string.  I assume you meant to implement `scanf_s(inputName, name);`.  You should have changed the first `push` to push the address of `inputName`.